# mysql - join two tables and group by the first table primary key but having second table rows too

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

My query is this in Laravel:

```
$rows = \DB::table('first_table')
    ->select('*', 'first_table.car_id AS car_id')
    ->leftJoin('second_table', 'first_table.car_id', 'second_table.car_id')
    ->where('first_table.user_id', $user_id)
    ->groupBy('first_table.car_id')
    ->get();
```

The result of query above will be all rows from `first_table` and `second_table` rows will be reduced to 1 because of that `groupBy`

I have a foreach loop and I want to iterate through each row of `first_table` BUT to have `second_table` to show too. However if I say `->groupBy('first_table.car_id')` it will reduce the `second_table` rows to 1 and if I say `->groupBy('second_table.offer_id')` it will show more rows than expected so what query should I set to show each row of `first_table` as an `li` in a `ul` list and show the `second_table` rows under the previous `li` as new `ul` list for each row?

**EDIT**

I want something like this:

```
first_table:
car_id  user_id price
7       1       60000
8       1       85000

second_table:
offer_id    car_id  offer_price
6           7       1000
7           7       5000
8           7       3000

foreach($rows as $row)
{
    <ul>
        <li>$row->price</li>
        <ul>
            foreach($row->offer_prices as $offer_price)
            {
                <li>$row->offer_price</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: `->leftJoin('second_table', 'first_table.car_id', '=',  'second_table.car_id')` missing `=` comparator

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `select *`

use

```
Select tablename1.columname1, tablename2.coloumnname2
```

Try this

```
$rows = Modelname::where('first_table.user_id', $user_id)
    ->select('tablename1.columname1', 'tablename2.coloumnname1', 'first_table.car_id AS car_id')
    ->leftJoin('second_table', 'first_table.car_id','=', 'second_table.car_id')
    ->groupBy('first_table.car_id')
    ->get();
```

Write first table's model name